# MRTK | HoloLens - Get all Triangles of a Mesh within an Object

Tags: unity-game-engine, spatial, mesh, mrtk

**- Question -**
I want to interact with the spatial mesh that I can access via MRTK. I want to instantiate a sphere at the cursor position and **get every triangle of the spatial mesh that is inside of the sphere, so I can cut that out and save it for me**.
I know how to

- instantiate and position the sphere
- get the spatial mesh via the scene understanding sdk

But I don't know how to approach this. To better understand what I want to try, I have drawn a small sketch:
[image]

**- Solution -**

1. Get collided objects via `TriggerEnter & -Exit`
2. My sphere has the `object manipulation script` from MRTK, that has an `EndOfManipulation-Event` that triggers, after placing the sphere.
3. Getting all `MeshFilter` and `Meshes`
4. Check via [collider.bounds.contains](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds.Contains.html) if point is inside my collider and save all those points to create a new mesh via the code from [@Pluto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63454917/5818081).
5. Combining meshes into one mesh and placing it somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Get the indices of vertices from `spatialMesh` that are inside the sphere -> `indicesList`
- From the  triangle array of `spatialMesh` get the triangles that have all the vertex indices inside `indicesList` -> `triangleList`

And you have all you need to construct a vertex array and triangle array for the mesh inside the sphere.

Just as an example:

```
for i = 0 to triangleList.Count
    newVertices[i] = spatialMesh.vertices[triangleList[i]];
    newTriangles[i] = i;
```

Comment: ok, thanks for responding. The problem is that I didnt get how to check if an vertices is inside my sphere. How do I determine whether a point or triangle is inside an object. The only thing I found was [this post](https://answers.unity.com/questions/611947/am-i-inside-a-volume-without-colliders.html) about creating planes and checking if the point is on the plane, but I guess this is not the right way.

Comment: @Perazim It's really easy to check if a point is inside a sphere. It's just `bool isInsideSphere = Vector3.Distance(point, sphereCenter) < sphereRadius`. For the triangles you only need to check if the indices are in the `indicesList`, like I said in the answer.

Comment: oh of course, you are right. Do you know how to achiev that if it would not be an sphere, but for example a cuboid or a cube? The distance would then not be a possible way.

Comment: @Perazim Again it's fairly easy if its axis aligned. Search for _axis aligned bounding box_ or _AABB_. There should be resources on the internet/SO on this topic, and if you don't find what you're looking for, you can post a separate question on SO.

Comment: I added my solution to my question. Thanks again!